# subject to a difference in degree

Tags: meaning

*What are these characteristics which are common, subject to a difference in degree, to all modern capitalism and to Fascism?*

Could you please explain to me the exact meaning of the phrase in parenthesis ("subject to a difference in degree"). Given the context I assume that the author asserts that modern capitalism and Fascism, despite some particular differences, are the same systems but the exact semantic structure I am not able to decipher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition *subject to a difference in degree* is intended to allow for magnitude deviation. The question only asks which characteristics are common and is not concerned with them being identical.

For example,

> What are the characteristics which are common, subject to a difference in degree, to all people?

You might choose to answer "weight" as a characteristic. There is a clear difference in degree amongst all people (everyone weighs a different value), but everyone has a weight.